# Some projects' dependencies contain unexplained code analyzers

Tags: c#, projects-and-solutions, roslyn-code-analysis

I have a couple of projects where under `Dependencies` there are one or two branches of code analyzers like this:

[image]

I tried the right mouse click on every branch as explaind [here](https://johnkoerner.com/csharp/using-analyzers-in-your-projects/) but there is no option to configure them and I also searched for `*.ruleset` files insinde the solution, I also check the packages as shown in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/roslyn-analyzers-overview?view=vs-2017) but there is nothing like that anywhere.

There is also nothing suspicious in the `.csproj` files, just some nuget packages that I've installed but nothing analyzer related.

How do I get rid of them? They give me warnings when I reference such projects in other solutions and `nuget restore` doesn't fix it either:

[image]

I have no idea where they come from. Some projects have them and others don't. However, they seem to somehow be related to `ASP.NET Core` or `MVC` packages that are installed in those projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've fixed the warnings by deleting the `microsoft.codeanalysis.analyzers` folder and executing `nuget restore`. They are still under `Dependencies` but at least the exclamation marks are gone.

I've also managed to remove the analyzers by adding the `<ExcludeAssets>analyzers</ExcludeAssets>` *directive* to each `AspNetCore` package:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.1.3">
  <ExcludeAssets>analyzers</ExcludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions" Version="2.1.1" >
  <ExcludeAssets>analyzers</ExcludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

Now they're finally gone.

Comment: You didn't fix the issues...you just removed the analyzers so the issues don't get reported. It's like taking your car to get a diagnostic check, and they tell you that your gas tank has saw dust in it, and to solve the problem you say "No way!" and leave the shop. Are you really sure sure that removing the analyzers was the proper course of action? I'd instead research each issue and try to understand what it is.

Comment: @mason I've fixed only the last two yellow lines that complain about the anlazyers. The results from the first screenshot are still there. It's easy for you to say that I should fix the actuall issue. These analyzers do not behave like those described in the `docs`. They are not clickable, they do not show you the code that is supposadly invalid, they are not configurable and reading them in the `properties` windows is really annoying because you cannot see anything. I'll just keep ignoring them because they aren't helpful. I don't even know why they are there in the first place! :-o

Answer (score 5):

There is a **bug in Visual Studio** and it is supposed to be fixed soon.
When Visual Studio loads all projects for the solution and tries to resolve all dependencies to display in Solution Explorer, some dependencies may fail and display as warnings with the path of the likely file for the dependency.

**Workaround:**

Right click the project with the warnings, and select `Unload Project` on the menu. Then right click it again and select `Reload Project`. Because Visual Studio is less busy with background processes than it was when it was loading everything for the entire solution, it is likely to resolve the dependency. It seems to always work for me.

Answer (score -1):

> Search Gcop in nuget package manager removes the installed packages
>   prefixed with GCop. this will remove the code analyzer references from
>   your project