# Visual Studio is not switching beween project and NuGet references without restarting

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, nuget, projects-and-solutions

I'd like to be able to switch between NuGet and project references. In order to achieve this I created custom solution and project configuration that I named `Debug.csproj`. I then moved packages to the appropriate section and put project reference in the other one:

```xml
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <PackageReference Include="..." Version="..." />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug.csproj|AnyCPU'">
    <ProjectReference Include=".." /> 
  </ItemGroup>
```

The problem I'm experiencing is that Visual Studio does switch between these to configurations without restarting it. I can select any configuration in the drop-down and nothing happens - the `Dependecies` tree remains the same (it's correctly configured in the `Configuration Manager`).

Is there a way to trigger the change without restarting Visual Studio? (not sure whether this is relevant but the only custom extension I use is ReSharper)

Comment: Recompile!!!  You have two different versions of the software.  If an entry point into the project dll does not exist or got moved you will fail unless the app is recompiled.  Make sure everything get recompiled.  I often delete the project bin folder to make sure everything gets recompiled.  Unless the dependencies specifically use the version number to force a recompile the project will not automatically compile.

Comment: @jdweng I tried recompiling, it does that without errors but `Dependecies` do not get updated. Do you think it's only a UI bug or does VS also use the wrong references for compilation?

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files

Comment: @jdweng awsome! You've actually fixed with that link my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53542703/some-projects-dependencies-contain-unexplained-code-analyzers/53543829#53543829) because now I'm able to get rid of the annoying anylzers from other projects by setting `<ExcludeAssets>analyzers</ExcludeAssets>` ;-) I still have to study it in order to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to trigger the change without restarting Visual Studio?

You can **unload your project and reload the project**. When you change the display in the Solution Explorer, you can trigger the change via reload the project file.

Since you have the same `Platform`, you can move it from the condition, like:

```
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <PackageReference Include="..." Version="..." />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug.csproj'">
    <ProjectReference Include=".." /> 
  </ItemGroup>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Makes sense to make the condition shorter... unfortuantelly VS still isn't happy with my idea of switching dependencies. Reloading is difficult with multiple projects ;-]

Comment: @t3chb0t, Indeed, if you have multiple projects, this workaround is not the best solution :(.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the approach that you describe in the question is that the condition is based on the build configuration. The Dependencies node in Solution Explorer does not appear to reevaluate if this changes.

It does however, appear to do so if you change a property. This is the approach that I went with and just changing the value of the `ShouldUsePackageReferencesInDebug` property and saving the project file was enough to result in the Dependencies node being reevaluated (I could see an item disappear from Packages and another appear in Projects - or vice versa).

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <ShouldUsePackageReferencesInDebug>false</ShouldUsePackageReferencesInDebug>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
    <PackageReference Include="<Package Name>" Version="1.0.0" Condition="$(ShouldUsePackageReferencesInDebug)" />
    <ProjectReference Include="<Project Path>" Condition="!$(ShouldUsePackageReferencesInDebug)" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
    <PackageReference Include="<Package Name>" Version="1.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Note that I have it set up so that our build pipeline which uses the `Release` build configuration will always use a PackageReference. That the condition here is based on the build configuration is not an issue as there is no instance of Solution Explorer that needs to be reevaluated.