# How can I reference a nuget package that contains a dependency on static code analyzers without introducing those analyzers into downstream projects?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dependencies, nuget, nuget-package

On a library I'm working on, which is deployed as a nuget package, I want to include `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading` so I can use `AsyncEventHandlers`.

However, the package depends on `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.Analyzers`  which contains static code analyzers. They produce a lot of warnings, some of which involve style rules that are not universally accepted.

I don't mind them in my library project, I find them helpful, however the analyzers infect all projects that reference my package. In one of my projects there were 500+ warnings telling me to add Async to the end of all async methods.

I was able to find some related issues: [Some projects' dependencies contain unexplained code analyzers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53542703/some-projects-dependencies-contain-unexplained-code-analyzers)

...But no direct hits. Is there a way to handle this in my package in such a way that these analyzers are turned off for downstream projects that consume my nuget package, without the end-developer having to take special action?

Comment: Hi Brian, PMF's answer is correct, you can do a test on your side. This is the official document: [Controlling dependency assets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets) :)

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT FYI, I haven't been able to get this to work in the case of transitive dependencies. See my comment on PMF's response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, analyzers shouldn't be included as dependencies. That's exactly what the linked question tries to tell you. Where the analyzer is included in the build, one normally uses the extra `<PrivateAssets>` and `<IncludeAssets>` directives, like so:

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.Analyzers" Version="1.0.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
```

Unfortunately, I'm not sure this also works if you're referencing the analyzers package indirectly (so when you reference `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading` instead of the analyzer package). But according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files) of these settings, this should work.

`<PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>` tells the compiler to not include the dependency for downstream code, while the `<IncludeAssets>` selection tells him to use the dependency for the given tasks.

Comment: I tried adding an explicit reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.Analyzers in order to use the PrivateAssets tag, but it didn't work unfortunately. Maybe it isn't possible. Thanks for the information though.